# Find the area of the region

Tags: calculus

$\int_{-2}^5 x-2dx$. Find the area of the region.

My attempt: I got the anti derivative of $x-2$ which is $\frac{x^2}{2}-2(x)$ , then subbed in 5 and -2 , $\frac{5^2}{2}-2(5)-\frac{2^2}{2}-2(-2)$ =$-3.5$. However, the answer is allegedly 12.5. Please tell me what I did wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Area is never negative. What you have found is the value of definite integral and not the area.

You can also calculate the area geometrically by drawing the given straight lines and adding the area of individual triangles.

To do it using integration method, you will need to break the limits like this.

x-2<0

x<2

This means that for x less than 2, the graph will lie below the x axis.

Now calculate the value of this definite integral whose limits go from -2 to 2 and take its mod because to calculate the area we are only concerned about the magnitude and not whether it lies below or above the x axis.

Then calculate the value of other definite integral whose limits go from 2 to 5. Add them to get the required area.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. An area is always *non-negative*.

Here one may write
$$
\mathcal{A}=\int_{-2}^5 \left|x-2\right|\:dx=\int_{-2}^2\color{red}{-\left(x-2\right)}\:dx+\int_{2}^5 \left(x-2\right)\:dx
$$ one may check that this gives $12.5$.

Comment: Where did you get the 2 to -2 and why is the plus the other function?

Comment: @Happy Where the integrand $x-2$ changes sign?

Comment: Yes and also how did u find the function going from 2 to -2?

Comment: @Happy Maybe you know that $|a|=-a$ if $a<0$, then $\left|x-2\right|=-(x-2)$ where $x-2<0$ which is the case when $x \in [-2,2]$.

Comment: Yes I know the absolute value but it didn't state that in the question or do you have to assume ?

Comment: I think this might come from the definition of the *area* in your course.